# Angular 1.2.22 routing issue with ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular.  `div ng-view` never works for me. Here is my code, this is copied and pasted from on of online demos. Thanks for help.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app="sampleApp">
   <head>
       <title></title>
       <script src="Scripts/angular-1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
       <script src="Scripts/angular-1.2.22/angular-route.js"></script>
       <script src="Scripts/AngularController.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body >

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
            <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>



  </body>
</html>
```

---Script AngularController.js----

```
'use strict';
  var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

    sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
       function ($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.
                       when('/addOrder', {
                           templateUrl: 'templates/routeOne.html',
                           controller: 'AddOrderController'
                       }).
                     when('/showOrders', {
                         templateUrl: 'templates/routeTwo.html',
                         controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
                     }).
                     otherwise({
                      redirectTo: '/routeThree.html'
            });
     }]);

   //--- Add Order Controller ----
   sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function ($scope) {

   });

  //--- Show Orders Controller ----
  sampleApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function ($scope) {

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues regarding your code. The first and most important is that your links are incorrect, they are missing a slash.

```
<li><a href="#/AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
<li><a href="#/ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
```

The second issue you are currently having is that on your route definition your otherwise is trying yo redirect to a file, where it actually should try to redirect to an angular defined route. An example of this could be something like this:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/routeThree.html'
})
.when('/addOrder', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/routeOne.html',
    controller: 'AddOrderController'
})
.when('/showOrders', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/routeTwo.html',
    controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

Cheers!